# How to create a pandas DataFrame from the selected few parts of the string

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have lines of string that look like below:

```
data = 
[15:07:29] (+?.?????????) host_name data: { cpu_id = 0 }, { var1 = 3, var2 = 4, var3 = 30, var4 = 87.7187 }
[15:07:30] (+0:0:1) host_name data: { cpu_id = 0 }, { var1 = 4, var2 = 4, var3 = 29, var4 = 0.073525 }
```

I want a pandas DataFrame similar to:

[image]

In doing so, I first split the lines on a new line, which resulted in a list and then dataframe:

```
data_list = data.split('\n')


['[15:07:29] (+?.?????????) host_name data: { cpu_id = 0 }, { var1 = 3, var2 = 4, var3 = 30, var4 = 87.7187 }', '[15:07:30] (+0:0:1) host_name data: { cpu_id = 0 }, { var1 = 4, var2 = 4, var3 = 29, var4 = 0.073525 }']

df=pd.read_csv(io.StringIO('\n'.join(split_lines)), delim_whitespace=True)
```

gives me a weird data-frame with 26 columns. I realized that the given string has `spaces` at irregular places. Is there a way to extract the interested data from the string and create a dataframe as shown in the above image?

Comment: The code that starts with `data = ...` doesn't seem to be valid Python. I suspect that you're going to have to do more than a bare split, though, instead writing a regex. You're probably looking at something like: `for line in data.splitlines():...`

Comment: @Mike you mean, Search pattern using RegEx would be a good approach?

Comment: Yeah. Or you could split on `"] ("`, then on `"host_name_data: "`, then on `"}, {"`, and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a very similar problem lately. It looks complicated at first, but if you have the same number of variables in each row, it is actually very easy to construct the regex.

```
import re
import pandas as pd

data = """
[15:07:29] (+?.?????????) host_name data: { cpu_id = 0 }, { var1 = 3, var2 = 4, var3 = 30, var4 = 87.7187 }
[15:07:30] (+0:0:1) host_name data: { cpu_id = 0 }, { var1 = 4, var2 = 4, var3 = 29, var4 = 0.073525 }
"""

def try_convert(s):
    try:
        v = float(s)
    except ValueError:
        v = s
    return v

def parse_data_string(s):

    regex = r"\[(\d.:\d.:\d.)\] \((.*)\) (\w+) data: { (\w+ = ([-+]?\d*\.\d+|\d+),*) }, { (\w+ = ([-+]?\d*\.\d+|\d+)), (\w+ = ([-+]?\d*\.\d+|\d+)), (\w+ = ([-+]?\d*\.\d+|\d+)), (\w+ = ([-+]?\d*\.\d+|\d+),? )}"

    matches = re.finditer(regex, s, re.MULTILINE)

    for match in matches:
        groups = list(match.groups())
        row = [try_convert(groups[i]) for i in {0,1,4,6,8,10,12}]
        yield row

df = pd.DataFrame(parse_data_string(data))

print(df)
print(df.dtypes)
```

I use `([-+]?\d*\.\d+|\d+)` to match the nummeric values, the rest of the regex is simple.

Conversion to the proper types can probably be done better.

Comment: I was just wondering what is the performance speed? With regex we need to process line by line and I feel it may take long time to process if the data we are processing is too large. Is there a better way (or) avoid regex and increase the processing speed?

Comment: Regexes are probably not the best performing solution but upfront its not clear that they are so bad either, since regex engines are highly optimized. Maybe hard encoding the variable names in the regex or so already helps to speed things up. If someone has another solution, we can compare.
For CSV, pandas has a C engine (selected by `read_csv(..., engine='C')`) that is optimized for speed. You could also consider writing a shared library for your specific problem.